# Violation of primary key C#

Tags: c#

El código insertado mas abajo es para registrar usuarios a una base de datos, pero al momento de repetir un dato me marca el error del **primary key**, se a que se debe pero no se como resolverlo gracias.

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
        con.Open();
        if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open && huella.Checked == true)
        {
            string q = "insert into Usser(Nombre,Id)values('" + txtusser.Text.ToString() + "','" + txtID.Text.ToString() + "')";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Trabajador registrado con exito","Usuario registrado con huella");
        }
```

Comment: La columna es PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: A que te refieres con "al momento de repetir un dato"?. A insertar un nuevo registro o a insertar un registro que ya está en la BD.?

Comment: asi es el dato ingresado ya esta en la primary key y lo que quiero es que el programa me avise que se esta repitiendo el dato para evitar un error en el progama

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podrias probar con encerrar la ejecucion de la query en un bloque Try Catch, para agarrar el lanzamiento de la excepcion.

Algo por el estilo

```
 private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
        con.Open();
        if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open && huella.Checked == true)
        {
            string q = "insert into Usser(Nombre,Id)values('" + txtusser.Text.ToString() + "','" + txtID.Text.ToString() + "')";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
            try{
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                MessageBox.Show("El usuario ya existe en la base de datos");
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Trabajador registrado con exito","Usuario registrado con huella");
        }
```

Comment: eso hare gracias por el aporte

Answer (score 3):

se me ocurre este tipo de control que puedes hacer:

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int existe = 0;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
    con.Open();
    if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open && huella.Checked == true)
    {

        string query = "select count(*) as existe from Usser where Id='"+ txtID.Text.ToString() +"' and Nombre = "+txtusser.Text.ToString();
        SqlCommand sqlcmmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        SqlDataReader dr = sqlcmmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            existe = Convert.ToInt32(dr["existe"]);
        }
        dr.Close();

        if(existe != 0)
        {
            string q = "insert into Usser(Nombre,Id)values('" + txtusser.Text.ToString() + "','" + txtID.Text.ToString() + "')";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Trabajador registrado con exito","Usuario registrado con huella");
        }
        else{
            MessageBox.Show("El trabajador ya estaba registrado.");
        }

    }
```

Comment: me gusta como queda este codigo, es mucho mas prolijo que generar una excecion y controlarla... seria la 2da opcion en las recomendaciones que realice :)

Answer (score 0):

bienvenido a StackOverflow en español.

Por lo que indicas, tu codigo te esta dando un error de sql server, debido a que intentas insertar un registro que ya existe en la base de datos.

La solucion a este problema depende de lo que estas deseando realizar:

si quieres que si ya existe no se haga nada, se me ocurren 2 soluciones:
- puedes envolver tu codigo en un try/catch y en el catch si es por una exception de primary key existente, no hacer nada...

Ejemplo sobre tu codigo:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
    con.Open();
    if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open && huella.Checked == true)
    {
      string q = "insert into Usser(Nombre,Id)values('" + txtusser.Text.ToString() + "','" + txtID.Text.ToString() + "')";
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      MessageBox.Show("Trabajador registrado con exito","Usuario registrado con huella");
    }
  }
  catch (SqlException ex)
  {
    // devolver mensaje de error...
    // SqlError err = ex.Errors[0];
    MostrarMEnsaje(ex.Message)
  }
}
```

- mas prolijo seria antes de insertar traer el dato y si es que existe no hacer nada.

Tambien podria ser que quisieras actualizar un registro basandote en el primary key, en ese caso seria intentar traer un registro y si existe hacer update...

Si quitaras la definicion de primary key de la base de datos te agregaria siempre el registro pero tendrias duplicados de ese campo que hoy tienes como pk, supongo no es algo que estes deseando.

Si cambiaras la definicion en la base de datos de tu actual campo que esta definido como primary key y lo dejaras como identity, seria un campo autoincremental y siempre insertaria uno nuevo y en este ejemplo que pasas, solo agregarias el nombre, siendo que el id ya lo generaria solo el motor.

Todo depende de que es lo que realmente deseas que suceda en base al dato que estas intentando insertar en la base de datos... si agregar mas info a la pregunta podré guiarte un poco mas en posibles soluciones.

Comment: Es exactamente a la primer solucion evitar la actualizacion de la base de datos para que no afecte el valor a la primary key y al progama

Comment: y gracias por la bienvenida

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que deduzco de tu pregunta, estás intentando insertar un registro en la BD que ya existe según su clave primaria (Id).

Para evitar que te lance una excepción de primary key utiliza un **try/catch** de la siguiente forma:

```
try
{
  _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  MessageBox.Show("Trabajador registrado con exito","Usuario registrado con huella");        
}
catch(SqlException sqlExc)
{
   MessageBox.Show("No se ha podido registrar el trabajador.");        
}
```